# How to read image file as base64 and send it back to request?

Tags: node.js

I am using the request module for reading image file from URL, and then I send it to request as JSON but the image data is corrupted.

```
const url = 'xxxxx';

request(url, null,(error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
   return res.status(200).json(body);
});
```

I don't get any error but the data is:

> "�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0002�\u0000\u0000\u0001�\u0008\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000i�\nc\u0000\u0000
>   \u0000IDATx��]\u0007x\u0015E�&\u0004�&�t\u0014�\u000f\u0010�\"���4����J\u0011A����J\n齓�;��....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending `json` which will change the response headers. In order to send the image with the correct headers you can simply pipe the response

```
request(url).pipe(res);
```

If you care about handling the response yourself, you can do:

```
request(url, { encoding: null }, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            // handle error
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, response.headers);
            res.end(body);
        }
    });
```